# convert py to exe does not work in other systems

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I've written a program with Python by using Selenium to search in Google for some specific keywords and open the first result.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import random
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome() 
driver.get("https://www.google.com/search?q=MyKeyWord")
time.sleep(2)  # Adjust the sleep duration as needed
driver.find_element_by_xpath('(//span/a)[1]').click()
total_height = int(driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight"))
for i in range(1, total_height, 2):
     driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, {});".format(i))
time.sleep(2) 
links = driver.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "li a")
random_link = random.choice(links)
random_link.click()
total_height = int(driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight"))
for i in range(1, total_height, 2):
     driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, {});".format(i))
time.sleep(5)
```

I've converted it to exe using Pyinstaller. It works fine in my laptop (Win10 64bit-chrome 121)
but it doesn't work in another laptop with Win 10 64bit and chrome 121.
Actually when I click on exe file in the second laptop nothing will happen and there's no error message shown.

Note: in the second laptop I haven't installed python, selenium and chromedriver.

Should I install Python, Selenium, or Chromedriver in the second laptop?
Is there any way to execute the converted exe file in any system with any version of Windows and Chrome?

I need the exe format of my Python program to execute in all Windows systems.